# Docker rmi: Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: powershell, docker

I am attempting to cleanup a (Windows) build server we use with our containers.

My goal is to periodically remove everything that isn't a base image, and I am doing this by filtering on our private registry name. I am running into this weird error when I try to use PowerShell for this:

```
PS C:\> docker images | Select-String "azurecr" | % { docker rmi $_ }
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

Here is me just running the `Select-String` filter on its own, which returns the images without issue:

```
docker images | Select-String "azurecr"
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

Despite what the error states, there are no uppercase characters in the registry or image name.

Also not working:

```
PS C:\> (docker images) -like '*azurecr*' | % { docker rmi $_ }
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

Comment: Screenshots of text are not an appropriate way to include content in a stack over flow question.  Please replace with the text itself.

Comment: `Select-String` doesn't produce simple strings as output. Try `(docker images) -like '*azurecr*'`.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, receiving the same error message from docker.

Comment: The command will give you the entire line. `docker rmi` expects the image ID, so you must extract that from the string for the command to work (`docker rmi ($_ -split '\s+')[2]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-like` operator for filtering the `docker images` output. Not only is it more lightweight than `Select-String`, but the latter also produces `MatchInfo` objects rather than passing just the matched strings through, which might cause undesired behavior. Also, you cannot just pass the full lines to `docker rmi`. The command expects an image ID, so you need to extract that from the string.

```
(docker images) -like '*azurecr*' | ForEach-Object {
    $id = ($_ -split '\s+')[2]
    docker rmi $id
}
```